# How do I update / flush / reset my DNS records in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista

How do I update / flush / reset my DNS settings from Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run `IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS` from an elevated command prompt.

This will flush your DNS cache, but not change your settings. If you actually want to change your DNS server, you will need to either set it statically, or run `IPCONFIG /RENEW` if your DNS server's settings have changed,

Comment: I was gonna answer my own question, but thanks! I'll take yours as the answer.

Comment: @Mark Tomlin Thank you. You got +15 from me too. :)

Comment: I think you got more then +15 by now :).

Comment: @Mark Tomlin Actually no, I was maxed for the day by the time I answered your question. I only got the 15, and I thank you greatly for it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open up a command prompt

   a. Start

   b. Run
2. type `ipconfig /flushdns` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.