# Determine actual DNS server consulted?

Tags: dns, traceroute

I know the authoritative DNS servers for records of a domain.  What I haven`t determined is where queries internal to our network are consulted for records.  I do know there are other servers used, serving different values internally, and would like to determine their IP addresses or servernames.  Even just the first one consulted would be a good start.

Assuming I flush my local DNS cache resolver first (`ipconfig /flushdns` and possibly [nbtstat](https://superuser.com/questions/435379/what-can-i-do-to-trace-the-origin-of-a-dns-resolution-in-windows-7) `-R`), is there a way to determine which hop in a `tracert` is the DNS (DHCP?) server that serves dns records within the network zone?

As a side note: I'm not sure if this is the same thing as a "serving a zone file", but gather the latter is related to more than just DNS.  Comments welcome to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind's dig tool will give you *an* answer:

```
$ dig
...
;; Query time: 9 msec
;; SERVER: fdcc:216f:1d2c::110#53(fdcc:216f:1d2c::110)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 22 06:49:54 UTC 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 239
```

The SERVER line has the address of the server that actually replied.

Comment: First stop is the firewall.  Any chance dig can show one hop past that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a "DNS conditional forwarder" in place that would send anyone internally to a specific DNS server.